# Carbon createFromFormat error -> Data missing

Tags: php, laravel, format, php-carbon

I understand that the length of the date string and format string must be the same, otherwise data missing error will be thrown.

My date string '13/03/2020 00:00'

This is how I write

```
$time=Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '13/03/2020 00:00');
```

I believe that my date string and format string are same but still getting Data missing error

Comment: Is that second parameter actually a hardcoded string, or does it come from a variable?

Comment: this error mostly occurs when your date string and the format is different.Be sure you are using the right format or the matched value.

Comment: Where/how are you using this code? Are you actually hardcoding the date value?

Comment: The example code you provided works just fine as is: https://web.tinkerwell.app/#/snippets/028ecd3c-80ff-4c56-8f13-b2d478d552b7. You'll need to provide the actual code you're having an issue with if you want to get some help.